# Using API from express.io route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io, express.io

I'm not sure how to use NodeJS API in combination with express.io
There is an API definition:

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    connection.query("select * from table") , function (error, results) {       
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else { 
            res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    });
});
```

How to transform API to use it with express.io?
I'm trying with `app.io.route`, but it's obviously wrong:

```
app.io.route('/api', function(req) {
    connection.query("select * from table", function (error, results) {     
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else { 
            req.end(JSON.stringify(results));
        }
    });
});
```